# Is it possible to install a custom class loader for java applets in the browser?

Tags: java, applet, classloader

I'll first admit that Java class loaders are a bit of a mystery to me.

What I'd like to do is define a class loader that would load any applets the browser encounters.  I know I can modify the policy file to grant elevated privileges and install a custom loader inside of an applet.  What I'd like to do is change the default class loader so that *any* applet is loaded through my loader.

Are there browser or plugin specific settings I could modify? Could I write my own browser plugin and configure the Java plugin through some API calls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can set the property java.system.class.loader property in the JRE runtime settings to replace the system class loader.